# Why is restarting client IE changing the username logged in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application. Some of my users reported that they see their username in "**domain\username**" format. When they close their IE and open it up back, username is shown as "**username**". Application shows "username" mostly. However, it shows "**domain\username**" every once in a while (I couldn't find the pattern).

What is the reason of this behavior?

Environment:

- Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7
- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- Anonymous and Forms authentications enabled. Others disabled
- Application pool idendity: “ApplicationPoolIdentity”
- In application pool settings, “Enable 32-Bit Applications” is “True”
- In application pool settings, “Managed Pipeline Mode” is “Integrated”
- Internet Explorer 11 is used in client
- Variable I use to get usernames: `User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Can you put the code you are using to display the username within your application in your question please?

Comment: Added (User.Identity.Name). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SiteMinder was creating the issue. Once it's installed in your web server, it may change your application's cookies even though your application is not protected by SiteMinder.